# Function in XNA game program that should clearly return with a non-null value returns null

Tags: c#, xna

I'm writing an XNA program in C#.

I have an my `Game` class, a class called `Player` and one called `Attack`.
I when I construct attack within my Game class, I pass in the game instance as a parameter like this:

`Attack attack(this);`

In Attack I have an instance of Player called `defender`. The Player class has a `getDefenseCard(Game game)` method.

Within Attack, I have a call to `defender.getDefenseCard(game)`, where `game` is the same instance of Game I passed to Attack in the constructor.

Within Player's `getDefenseCard(Game game)` I make a call to `game.getCard()`, which is a method in my Game class that checks to see if the user has clicked on a card and if so, it returns the card clicked. This is accomplished by checking the position of the mouse and whether there was a click.

The behaviour is looking for is that the card selected by the player will be returned all the way to Attack where it is processed. This is in fact the behaviour I get.

However there is one problem I'm experiencing. I want to give the player the option to select no cards. To accomplish this I have created a `Card` object called `noDefense` as an attribute of the Game class and initialized it to a value. The plan is that when my attack object receives this particular card it will process a no defense response.

To get this noDefense to the attack object I created a boolean value and a button. When the button is pressed, the boolean value is set to true. Within `getCard`, I first check to see if this boolean is true. If so I set it false and return the noDefense Card.

The problem I'm having is that while the button works and the `getCard` method does enter the if statement, the value that Player's `getDefenseCard` receives when `getCard` returns is a `null` object. Which is baffling, because I'm returning a non-null Card object.

Here is a simplified code to make the whole situation a little less narrative and more demonstrated:

```
class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    bool noDefenseSelected = false;
    Card noDefenseCard;
    Attack attack = new Attack(this);
    Button refuseDefense = new Button();

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        noDefenseCard = new Card("no defense");
        refuseDefense.onClick += noDefenseButtonClicked; 
    }   

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Attack.resolve();
    }

    public Card getCard()
    {
        if (noDefenseSelected)
        {
            noDefenseSelected = false;
            return noDefenseCard;
        }

        if (mouseNotOverCard())
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (mouseNotClicked())
        {
            return null;
        }

        return getCardFromClick();
    }

    public void noDefenseButtonClicked(Button b)
    {
        noDefenseSelected = true;
    }
}

class Player
{
    public Card getDefenseCard(Game game)
    {
        return game.getCard();
    }
}

class Attack
{
    Game game;
    Player defender = new Player();

    public Attack(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void resolve()
    {
        Card card = defender.getDefenseCard(game);
        if (card != null)
        {
            dealWithDefenseCard(card);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the problem is that I do know for sure that the button works, `getCard` enters the first conditional, but for some reason it returns with `null` instead of `noDefenseCard`. If anybody could explain to me why that is and how to fix it, I'd be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: If you break on the `return noDefenseCard` statement, and check `noDefenseCard`, is it non-null? Are you sure that the `Initialize` function is being called and actually instantiating `noDefenceCard`?

Comment: Initialize is actually part of the XNA framework and contains a whole many lines of code that don't appear here. If it was never called the program couldn't run.

But I did check specifically whether noDefenseCard is null or not before I return it and it is not null.

Comment: OK, just for fun, change `return noDefenseCard` to `return new Card("TEST")` and verify that this is what is received by `Card card = defender.getDefenseCard(game);` (incidentally, why not just call game.getCard()?)

Comment: Thanks. The initial version was return new Card("no defense"), I changed it to the current version after that didn't work. The reason I'm not calling game.getCard from Attack is that there is a whole lot of context that I ommited from the example code, and it makes sense for a Player object to return the card instead of getting it from the Game object.

Comment: OK, well from the code you have posted, it should work - there must be something you have omitted which you felt was not part of the problem but is in fact causing the issue. See the code I have posted below which shows that it should work.

Comment: While I doubt it's the source of your problem, you **really** should be calling `base.Initialize()` in your overridden `Initialize` method. That will enumerate `Components` and initialize them all as well. (Even if this program has an empty `Components` collection, you should get in the habit of calling `base.Initialize()`.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I actually do call base.Initialize(), I just didn't include it in the this sample code as it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have stripped out a lot of stuff (that was never being invoked in your posted code anyway) to get this to compile but the general structure is the same as what you posted, and it works in LinqPad.

I have a feeling that some code you have not posted is the cause of the problem...

```
 void Main()
    {
        Game g= new Game();
        g.Initialize();
        Attack a = new Attack(g);
        Card c = a.resolve();
        Console.WriteLine(c.name); //prints "no defense"

    }

//just a guess as to what Card looks like.
    public class Card
    {
        public string name{get;set;}
        public Card(string name){this.name=name;}
    }

    public class Game 
    {
        bool noDefenseSelected = false;
        Card noDefenseCard;

//this is manually called in this example
        public void Initialize()
        {
           noDefenseCard = new Card("no defense");
           noDefenseSelected=true;
        }   

        public Card getCard()
        {
          if (noDefenseSelected)
          {
             noDefenseSelected = false;
             return noDefenseCard;
          }
         //all other cases return null in this example.
          return null;
        }

    }

      public  class Player
      {
         public Card getDefenseCard(Game game)
         {
           return game.getCard();
         }
      }

      public class Attack
      {
         Game game;
         Player defender = new Player();

         public Attack(Game game)
         {
            this.game = game;
         }

         public Card resolve()
         {
            Card card = defender.getDefenseCard(game);
//returning card in this case for the example so it can be printed.
            return card;
           }
}
```

Comment: Well, the code above is simple C#, not an XNA game, a very different context.

Comment: I have stripped out the irrelevant stuff. The core is the same. I don't have the XNA F/W installed on my current machine and FYI I have used XNA before. My point is that you keep talking about "context" when it is absolutely clear that you have not posted all the relevant code, because my stripped down example, which has the *exact same* control flow as your posted code, works just fine => you omitted some of this "context" which you feel is not important, but which actually is!